# SWIG generates invalid Python wrapper code

Tags: python, swig

It is a wierd problem that sometimes happens when I use [SWIG](http://swig.org/) to generate a Python wrappers. It happens with both Swig 2.x and 3.x versions. I don't know what triggers it, but sometimes after code refactoring, this error appears.

The problem is that SWIG generates code that is not valid Python, but some kind of pseudo-code. For example

```
class SwigPyIterator(_object):

    ... note that method definitions are not Python:

    def value(self) -> "PyObject *" : return _vabamorf.SwigPyIterator_value(self)
    def incr(self, n : 'size_t'=1) -> "swig::SwigPyIterator *" : return _vabamorf.SwigPyIterator_incr(self, n)
    def decr(self, n : 'size_t'=1) -> "swig::SwigPyIterator *" : return _vabamorf.SwigPyIterator_decr(self, n)
```

I am using `setuptools` and here are the lines relevant to SWIG:

```
swigging estnltk/pyvabamorf/vabamorf.i to estnltk/pyvabamorf/vabamorf_wrap.cpp
swig -python -c++ -py3 -o estnltk/pyvabamorf/vabamorf_wrap.cpp estnltk/pyvabamorf/vabamorf.i
```

Does anyone know, what triggers this behaviour and how to fix it? I have been able to fix this in the past, but I have never been able to trace down specific changes that made this problem disappear.

Comment: Hmm, it works correctly with Python2, but not Python3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Master turned the Novice toward the door, and with a supportive hand on his shoulder said, "Go young Novice, and Read The Fucking Manual." And so the Novice became enlightened.*

Ok, this was a stupid user error.
This was actually expected behavior and this pseudo-code is actually something called [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107).

It is also documented in [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html)

```
The -py3 option will enable function annotation support. When used SWIG is able to generate proxy method definitions like this:

  def foo(self, bar : "int" = 0) -> "void" : ...
```

It seems I managed to confuse myself not cleaning all files between Python2/Python3 compiles and got distracted also by some import related errors introduced during refactoring.

Dang, I have not managed to surprise myself so much in a while.